# jQuery clone, form values and emptying

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery tat I'm using from a fiddle (working with it to work with my site for testing).

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var regex = /^(.*)(\d)+$/i;
    var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;

    $("button.clone").click(function(e){
        $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
            .insertBefore(copy)
            .attr("id", "clonedInput" +  cloneIndex)
            .find("*").each(function() {
                var id = this.id || "";
                var match = id.match(regex) || [];
                if (match.length == 3) {
                    this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
                }
        });
        cloneIndex++;
        return false;
    });

    $("button.remove").click(function(){
        $(this).children(".clonedInput").remove();
    });
});
```

Two issue that I am having, which are probably caused by one issue is when I remove one of the "cloned" fields, it removes all of the other fields besides the parent, and when I clone a field, it only works off of the parent and keeps the original values...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you give us the HTML used or, better, a http://jsfiddle.net of it ? I'm pretty sure it's about the `click` event, it should be `on` or, at least, `live`. Having the HTML can help me to know if I'm right or not.

Comment: Of course, didnt even think about that.

http://jsfiddle.net/bendrumin/N3FGW/

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, I used the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to achieve what you wear trying to do.
The `click` method is an alias to the [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method. The `bind` method isn't *dynamic*, you bind an event to a node and that's all. The [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) methods are dynamics, they don't just bind an event to a node but check is the event and the node are matching (I'll explain).
Finally, the `on` method is here to harmonize those 3 methods. Here is what I've done :

```
// On all the <form>s
$('form')
.on(
    // When we click inside the <forms>
    'click',
    // If the clicked element match the selector, so if it has the clone class
    '.clone',
    // We do stuff
    function(){
        // Do stuff
    });
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/N3FGW/3/).